# What is the regex for : Allow only letters and spaces but not start with space?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program  that let people enter their infomation (name, age....) .For the name input I don't want them to left blank and allow only letters and spaces but not start with space.
What is the appropriate regex? I tried with : `^[a-zA-Z\\s]*$` but it didn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: Think about it this way: the first character has different requirements, so you need to express it differently... (You should also consider allowing hyphens and apostrophes, by the way...)

Comment: you could also allow this and use `trim()` or something along those lines. This might help with the regex: [http://www.regexper.com](http://www.regexper.com/#%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5Cs%5D*%24)

Comment: A more common practice would be to allow spaces at both ends during user input, then `trim()` it automatically as keyser has suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the first character separately:

```
^[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z\\s]*$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*$

Answer (score 1):

`^([a-zA-Z]+\s*)+$` should do the job

Comment: it almost do the job but it still allow blank.Thank you , anyway

Comment: @hello_java have you spot my last edit? Isn't that perfect now?